# Nodejs Passport Failure message not working

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, authentication, passport.js

I have Passport Local working on my app.

Success brings authenticates and failure does not.
However im trying to make it fail better through fail messages and escaping the action.

Tried following the passport documentation.

The error messages are not appearing for some reason, would appreciate some assistance!

here is the local startegy

```
// Configure the local strategy for use by Passport.
passport.use(new Strategy(
  function(username, password, cb) {
    db.users.findByUsername(username, function(err, user) {
      if (err) { return cb(err); }
      if (!user) { return cb(null, false,req.flash('message','Invalid username or password')); }
      if (user.password != password) { return cb(null, false,req.flash('message','Invalid username or password')); }
      return cb(null, user);
    });
  }));
```

The authentication

```
//Home
app.post('/home.ejs',
  passport.authenticate('local'),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

I also have another attempt at authentication if this is more accurate but also had no luck

```
  //Home
  app.post('/home.ejs', function( req, res, next) { passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {

            if (err) { return next(err);  req.flash('message','Invalid username or password') }

            if (!user) { return res.redirect('/');  failureFlash: 'Invalid username or password' }

            req.logIn(user, function(err) {
            if (err) { return next(err); }
              return res.redirect('/');

        });
      })(req, res, next);
    });*/
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy ...
```

instead of your

```
passport.use(new Strategy(.....
```